# log4net generic type loggers on WCF Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, windows-services, log4net

Does anyone know why log4net would initialise loggers differently when WCF process is a console app and when it is a Windows Service?

```
public class GenericType<T> : where T : class
{
    public GenericType()
    {
        log = LogManager.GetLogger("Namespace.MyLogger");
    }
}
```

in console app the logger is "MyLogger", in windows service it is "GenericType`1".

It seems that in windows service log4net enforces something like:

```
log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
```

The processes are started using this code:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(params string[] parameters)
    {           
        var service = new Service();
        if (parameters.Length > 0 && parameters[0].ToLower() == "/c")
        {
            service.RunConsole();//Calls service.OnStart()
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(service);
        }

    }
}
```

So if we run it as a console we pass "/c" argument. When we run it as a Win service, it is instaleld as a service and is executed without "/c". This is the only difference, so type loading is identical.

Non generic loggers are initialised just fine.

**EDIT:**

Simplified exapmple

Comment: nameOfT = typeof(T).Name; T is not generic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behaviour you describe is related to the availability of your types in the calling application, this depends on the way you reference the object T and the way you expose it as data contract or via shared class libraries like core or interfaces...

Can you explain more about your architecture and c# projects stack?

Log4Net has no issue in this, is more an issue on how the type name is resolved from different consumers.

Comment: +1. You are just passing a string to log4net so it has no knowledge of your type.

Comment: Xavier, so that is exactly what I want - init logger with a string, but when you run it as a service it initialises logger with a type and I don't know why, the code is exactly the same.

Comment: @Al Bundy, code is the same but retrieves different values, would work the same also if not using Log4Net but doing a Console.Write... Fix the issue in your code first then go ahead with L4N or change the way you init the logger with a static constant string.

Comment: Davide, what do you mean "code is the same but retrieves different values", also could you please point an "issue with my code" that I could fix?